# How to change binding after the element has been drawn in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change the binding of an element after it has been drawn on the screen. 
Scenario: when an input element renders for the first time it is bonded to a model variable. but now user selects some option in other drop down and depending upon the same I now have to show some different value but not to touch the existing model value. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you could bind to a property in a variable like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="variables[activeVariable]">
```

Add a button to change the variable been target

```
<div  ng-click="selectVar()">change target var</div>
```

And in your controller bind the variables

```
$scope.activeVariable = ''
$scope.variables = {
   var1:'test 1', 
   var2:'test 2'
}
$scope.selectVar = () => $scope.activeVariable = $scope.activeVariable == 'var1' ? 'var2' : 'var1'
```

When you change the target variable, it stils watching it and will change correctly on user inputs

Comment: for single property it seems fine but it is not feasible if we use a form which is having its every element bound to a model. conditional expression for each property is not practical.

Comment: what about make many depth deep variables like: variables[activeForm][activeVariable] or variables[activeForm].name

Comment: No actually, I come up with some different workaround. Using value attribute. dynamically setting the ng-model attribute's value to empty (which will keep my model intact) and at the same time using 'value' attribute to set the element with whatever value I want to set. This is working fine for me.

Comment: Nice, sorry I couldn't help